# How to call url on button click in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am passing a URL when the user clicks on a button with this method, but my application crashes and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I've written this code (the one that handles the connection) in another Controller which is being called from the button event in the first view.

In particular, this line of code:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

Produces the following error:

> /Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/RegexKitLiteDemo/Classes/SearchView.m:19:0 /Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/RegexKitLiteDemo/Classes/SearchView.m:19: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSURL *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'URLWithString:' from distinct Objective-C type

Here's the full code:

```
- (void)LoadAirport

{    
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bookryanair.com/SkySales/FRSearch.aspx?AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24ButtonSubmit=Search%20For%20Flights%20&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay1=<%i>&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay2=<%i>&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDestination1=<%@>&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth1=<%i>&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth2=<%i>&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketOrigin1=<%@>&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_ADT=1&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_CHD=0&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT=0&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24RadioButtonFlowSelector=FlightAndCar&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24RadioButtonMarketStructure=RoundTrip&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24discountPax=0&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTTARGET=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUBMGRkg4UKvNNb1NbM14%2F2n9zUxhNQ%2B%2BA%3D&errorlist=",day,day1,DestinCode,fromDate1,fromDate2,OriginCode];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"%@",webData);
    } else {

    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    //responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [webData setLength: 0]; 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    //[responseData appendData:data];
    [webData appendData:data]; 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    [connection release];
    [webData release]; 
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    //[textView setString:@"Unable to fetch data"];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    [connection release];
}
```

Comment: What you doing wrong is you are assigning NSUrl to a string object in above code line, [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url], in this line url is not an NSString as expected parameter its a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure the error occurred due to the lack of concentration ;-) You are passing an *NSURL* instance as argument where you are supposed to pass a *NSString*.

On the line,

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:...
```

either set,

```
requestWithURL:url
```

or,

```
requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use This  Code for `NSURLRequest`.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```